# Why is ES6 default parameter function not defined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const foo = () => 'foo!';

const doAThing = (
    foo = foo
) => {
    console.log(foo)
}

doAThing();
```

Gives the following:

```
/private/var/folders/xp/n5tbdrrs761ck82qqychcf61ptmq9d/T/CodeRunner/Untitled.js:4
    foo = foo
          ^

ReferenceError: foo is not defined
    at doAThing (/private/var/folders/xp/n5tbdrrs761ck82qqychcf61ptmq9d/T/CodeRunner/Untitled.js:4:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/xp/n5tbdrrs761ck82qqychcf61ptmq9d/T/CodeRunner/Untitled.js:9:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:423:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:147:9)
```

(If I make it `_foo = foo` then it works.)
Why is foo not defined in my example?

Comment: `foo` is also a constant :thinking:

Comment: The parameter `foo` shadows the outer `foo`, even in default values.

Comment: Presumably because in that scope `foo` refers to the value of the parameter, which you haven't set yet. See e.g. http://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html#parameter-default-values-and-the-temporal-dead-zone

Comment: Don't pick the same name for parameter values as high scoped variables because the more local definition will "hide" the higher scoped one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is foo not defined in my example?

Evaluating the parameter definition creates a new scope where parameters are defined. That allows you to refer to parameters in default values, e.g.

```js
function foo(x, y=x) {
  console.log(x, y);
}
foo(42);
```

And because of that, the second `foo` in `foo=foo` actually refers to the *parameter* `foo` itself. It shadows the "outer" `foo`. But you cannot refer to `foo` at this point because it wasn't initialized yet.

Think about it as being the same as

```
let x = x;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const foo = () => 'foo!'; //1
                          //2
const doAThing = (        //3
    foo = foo             //4
) => {                    //5
    console.log(foo)      //6
}                         //7

doAThing();
```

On line 3, you write `foo = foo`. Here you are trying to both declare a variable and also use that variable before it is declared. Because you gave your parameter the name `foo`, it is attempting to reference itself when you write `foo = foo`. The right side of that assignment will not be the function `foo` you declared above it. To fix this, change your parameter name.

```
const foo = () => 'foo!'; //1
                          //2
const doAThing = (        //3
    func = foo            //4
) => {                    //5
    console.log(func)     //6
}                         //7

doAThing();               // -> () => 'foo!'
```